CSS Gradient Border Not Applied to Rounded Button
I'm trying to create an html button with a rounded gradient colored border. I am using react css modules. However, the gradient doesn't seem to be applied when both the secondary and rounded classes are applied. Here is the relevant CSS code:
.button {
  font: var(--button);
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 16px 24px 16px 24px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:focus-visible {
  outline: 3px solid var(--focus-outline);
  outline-offset: 0;
}

.rounded {
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.secondary {
  color: var(--blue);
  border: 1px solid var(--blue);
  border-image: linear-gradient(270deg, #0073E8 0%, #10559A 100%) 1 stretch;
  background-color: var(--white);
}

.secondary.rounded {
  border: 1px solid var(--blue);
  border-image: repeating-linear-gradient(270deg, #0073E8 0%, #10559A 100%) 40px round;
}

This is what I am trying to achieve

But I get this instead

What is the correct way to do this?

Please add minimal reproducible example
